Robot framework test Automation with Request body multipart/form-data
How can I form a form-data using JSON file and CSV file in robot framework?
I have tried this.
${filespart}=    Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary    ${filespart}    ${body}
    Set To Dictionary    ${filespart}    1A=${file}
    ${response}=    Post Request   sessions    ${param}   files=${filespart}    headers=${header}

